# Reload network settings from ifcfg-* files in openSUSE 13.2

Tags: networking, opensuse, network-interface

An application I'm working on writes the network settings by updating the `/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-*` files. Unfortunately these settings are not reloaded because every time I do `ifconfig` there is no IP on the interface I'm updating.

I tried adding `ONBOOT='yes'` to that file.
Also `ifconfig eth0 up`.
And `ifup eth0` but it ends up with a timeout error.

But if I do `ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.5/24` for example it works but that IP does not appear in the `ifcfg-eth0` file for examples.

So my questions are:

1. By setting the IP using `ifconfig`, Where is the location of these settings is stored ?
2. In my situation where I write to the `ifcfg-eth0` how to reload the settings from that file ?

Note: The machine that I'm working on has no `NetworkManager`.

Note 2: The machine is on a remote location and I'm connecting to it through SSH using putty.

Note 3: As of [this](https://www.suse.com/documentation/suse91/suselinux-adminguide/html/ch14s03.html) documentation page section 14.3.1.1 the command `ifup` will bring the interface up and reads its corresponding configuration from `ifcfg-*` file. Somehow the command `ifup eth0` ends up with

```
wicked: device enp2s0: operation timed out
enp2s0          setup-in-progress
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do a `/etc/init.d/network restart` this is usually reentrant and will only change what is updated.

`ifconfig` is an interactive tool which only relies on what you provide as argument, those arguments are not saved somewhere.

Comment: There is no `network` script under `/etc/init.d/`. I tried `service network restart` and it did not work. I don't know why there is no `network` script, I did not install that machine.

Comment: And by didn't work I mean that `ifconfig` does not show the new IP in that file.

Comment: It seems this version of suze is based on systemd and not init.d, this might explain why you have nothing in  `/etc/init.d/`

Comment: The directory `/etc/init.d/` exists and there is network conf files like `ifcfg` but no script called `network`. OK there is a `systemd directory where to go there ?

Comment: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd.service.html

Comment: Unfortunately the service `systemd-networkd.service` does not exist. Also no configuration files exists in the mentioned directories.

Comment: i see you have wicked, then you should read https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles-12/book_sle_admin/data/sec_basicnet_manconf.html

Comment: That's excellent bro! `systemctl restart wickedd.service` did the magic, it worked on my machine, I will test it on the remote machine and tell you. Thanks in advance!

Comment: good to know :) happy sysadmin ! :)

Comment: For some reason, even after restarting that service, the `ifup` and `wicked ifup` commands both give me "General failure" on the local machine.

Comment: that's another topic ! :)

Answer (score 1):

For systemd and later

```
sudo systemctl restart network
```

Comment: Noting that a [`systemctl restart wickedd.service` comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228766/reload-network-settings-from-ifcfg-files-in-opensuse-13-2/521738#comment390064_228768) from the other answer seems to have solved this specific problem.